# Sentiment analysis in R by row

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am performing a sentiment analysis of a dataframe. Each row of the data frame has a "text" variable that consists of several words. I wish to perform a sentiment analysis by counting the positive and negative words through the "bing" lexicon. However, when I use the code:

```
sentiment <- tokens %>%
      inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% # pull out only sentimen words
      count(sentiment) %>% # count the # of positive & negative words
      spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% # made data wide rather than narrow
      mutate(sentiment = positive - negative) %>% # # of positive words - # of negative owrds
```

I get the count of all the entries in the dataframe.

Is there any way to get the count by row of the dataframe.

For example, the following are the rows of the data frame

```
user_id        text
1234           "Hello world"
1255           "Have a lot of fun"
```

When I use the previous code it would count the number of positive and negative entries of the text variable in both entries. I want it to only count the positive and negative of each row.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I have done an edit, hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: In that case, you may have `count(user_id, sentiment)`

Comment: but that wouldnt work because i need to tokenize it.

Comment: Not clear without knowing that `tokens` is?

Comment: Isn't `tokens` already tokenised ? Do you mean to use `tokens %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>%  count(user_id, sentiment)`

Comment: `df %>% unnest_tokens(word, text, token = 'words') %>% left_join(get_sentiments('bing')) %>% mutate(sentiment = if_else(sentiment == 'positive', 1, -1, missing = 0)) %>% group_by(user_id) %>% summarise(sentiment = sum(sentiment))`